# В чем разница между null и undefined?

Tags: javascript

В чем разница между null и undefined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- null - пустое значение (явно присваивается)
- undefined - неприсвоенное значение (по-умолчанию)

В то же время, null и undefined будут считать равными, напр.:

```
var x = null;
var y;
if (x == y) {
    // выполнится
}
```

Comment: Однако, null === undefined даст false, так что не следует думать, будто эти вещи одно и то же. К тому же, у них разные типы. null - это объект (хотя и идёт речь о его отсутствии), а undefined и имеет тип "undefined"

Answer (score 2):

Вот так отличается их поведение:

```
null >= 0 -> true
null == 0 -> false
null <= 0 -> true

null > 0 -> false
null < 0 -> false

null - 0 = 0

undefined >= 0 -> false
undefined == 0 -> false
undefined <= 0 -> false

undefined > 0 -> false
undefined < 0 -> false

undefined - 0 = NaN

undefined >= null -> false
undefined == null -> true
undefined <= null -> false
```

Comment: тогда уж было бы не плохо написать **почему** такие результаты.

Comment: http://javascript.ru/ecma/part11 вот тут можно найти информацию. В частности - алгоритмы сравнения.

Comment: И эта информация нужна в ответе, а не просто непонятный блок кода.

Answer (score 2):

Отличие Null и Undefined

1. Вообще появление в JS 2х типов данных обозначения отсутствия значения - это ошибка проектирования языка, и насколько я знаю ни в одном другой языке программирования нет 2х типов обозначающих отсутствие значения.
2. `Undefined` задается по умолчанию при объявлении переменной, когда мы еще на задали ей какое-то значение (т.е неопределенное отсутствие значения), а `Null` мы можем только задать (т.е является определённым значением отсутствия).
3. `Null` - в typeof это `object`, а `undefined` - это `undefined`.
4. `JSON` - может работать с `Null` но не может с `Undefined`.
5. А еще `Null` и `Undefined` при нестрогом сравнении равны друг другу, равны самим себе, и больше ничему. Они являются в логической интерпретации как `false`, но при сравнении они не равны `false`.
6. Использование - обычно `undefined` не задают, а если он приходит - а мы ожидали какое-то значение, то где-то есть баг. А `Null` - задают целенаправленно.

Answer (score 0):

Только что проведенный тест в консоли Firefox дал странный результат:

```
var a = null;
var b;
alert(a+'/'+b+'/'+(typeof(a)==typeof(b))+'/'+(a==b)); // null/undefined/false/true 
alert(c); // ошибка, как и с "b==c" и "if (c) {}"
```

Я не знаю, как это объяснить с т.з. логики. Видимо, как-то различаются "объявленный undefined"(b) и "совсем undefined"(c), при этом типы null и undefined не равны, но значения их равны(видимо, потому что пустые). Однако, вам должно быть интересно, что ошибок с необъявленной переменной не вызовет только конструкция "if (typeof(c)=='undefined') {}"

Comment: Ну да, в этом нет ничего странного. Это обычное поведение. null == undefined, и в то же время null === undefined  => false. По поводу "if (typeof(c)=='undefined') {}"   - это также нормальное поведение. Дело в том, что typeof - это не функция, а оператор JavaScript. В то время как alert(c) - это попытка вызова функции.

Answer (score -1):

- `null` - это пустое или несуществующее значение
- `null` должен быть присвоен
- `undefined` чаще всего означает, что переменная была объявлена, но не определена
- при поиске несуществующих ключей в объекте мы также получим `undefined`
- при использовании typeof для проверки `null` он возвращает объект, `undefined` же возвращает `undefined`
- в функции с параметрами по умолчанию undefined будет использовать значение по умолчанию, а `null` - нет
- JSON может обрабатывать только `null`, но не `undefined`

Взял вот [отсюда](https://devarticles.space/articles/null-vs-undefined/). Там расписано подробнее и с примерами, если интересно.